# Installing Grails Spock Plugin in 2.0.0M1

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spock

I'm kicking the tires on Grails 2.0.0M1 and Springsource Tool Suite 2.7.1, but I'm having problems installing the spock plugin.

When I run "grails install-plugin spock 0.6-groovy-1.8-SNAPSHOT" I get:

```
| Downloading: spock-0.6-groovy-1.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
        grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-spock/tags/RELEASE_0_6-groovy-1_8-SNAPSHOT/spock-0.6-groovy-1.8-SNAPSHOT.pom: expected='org.grails.plugins' found='org.spockframework'
| Error resolving plugin [name:spock, group:org.grails.plugins, version:0.6-groovy-1.8-SNAPSHOT]. Plugin not found.
| Error Plugin not found for name [spock] and version [0.6-groovy-1.8-SNAPSHOT]
```

Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem. This was fixed earlier today. Try `grails install-plugin spock 0.6-SNAPSHOT` (without "groovy-1.8").

See:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPOCK-5?focusedCommentId=65695&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-65695

Answer (score 1):

Grails 1.4/2.0 requires Groovy 1.8, but they have some problems with getting Spock version with support for it into Maven Central. The method described [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPOCK-2?focusedCommentId=64393&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-64393) worked OK for us with Grails 1.4.M1. It's a little cumbersome, because it requires to manually build the JAR and install it into the local Maven repository (thus, needs to be performed on every machine), but you can also try to deploy it to a local Nexus/Artifactory.