# Grails 2.0.0.RC1 error Spock testing

Tags: grails, spock

I've upgraded a grails project from Grails 1.3.5 to Grails 2.0.0.RC1 and the Spock plugin from 0.5 to 0.6. and now have this error in tests:

```
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/appName
| Server stopped
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in target\test-reports
| Error Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could
ad class in test type 'spock' (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade your Spock plugin to spock:0.6-SNAPSHOT. There is a related [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974810/installing-grails-spock-plugin-in-2-0-0m1) and it references a [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPOCK-5?focusedCommentId=67107&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-67107).

Extracted is this:

The following in the repositories section:

```
mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots"
```

And the following plugin dependency definition

```
test ":spock:0.6-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: Yes. As I've written before I'd updated spock plugin from 0.5-groovy-1.7 to 0.6-SNAPSHOT. with version 0.5 I'd got compilation errors. Discussed error occurs after application has been compiled and started.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your local grails cache for the project. To do this,

go into ~/.grails/2.0.0RC1/projects (where ~ is your home directory) and delete the project directory.

You may also need to clean and build, as a latest build of Spock a couple of days ago required [all spock tests to be recompiled](http://groups.google.com/group/spockframework/browse_thread/thread/04335c015fbdcfdd#).

Answer (score 0):

0.7 is released now; for grails 2.1/2.0 you can use now:

```
    grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  plugins {
    test ":spock:0.7"
  }
}
```